# AWS Lambda - RDS Proxy creating a connection takes more time

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

As we can't use native DBCP or any kind of java connection pool in AWS Lambda I have been using RDS proxy to connect MYSQL DB, But Still it takes 5 to 6 secs to make connection but I need the response from the lambda in <1 secs it there any way of keeping the connection warm. I'm using *DriverManager.getConnection* to get connection from RDS proxy

I have tired to connect proxy using
*java.sql.DriverManager*

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(("DB_Primary_IP"),("DB_Username"),("DB_Password"));
```

Comment: you could put the `DriverManager.getConnection` outside the handler so that it is shared across lambda invocation within the same execution environment. In order to reduce even more this init time, you could use provision concurrency, so that your lambda is warm and ready to serve request.

Comment: Thanks for the replay . Provision concurrency may be the most related answer for this issue.